# Nodejs - class with async await does nothing

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am fairly new to Node.JS, but have some experience in other languages. I am trying to achieve the following:

- I want to perform a task and if it fails perform another task.

I have two files: one is the main function, the other contains the class.
First the main function (main.js):

```js
(async function main() {
        let { MyClass } = require("./my_class.js");
        const mc = new MyClass();

        await mc.do_stuff();
        console.log(mc.message);
})();
```

The other is the class (my_class.js)

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.message='hello';
  }

  do_stuff=async function() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => async function (){
       let [res,rej]=await do_first('fail');
       if(rej) {
          console.log('do_first() failed.');
          [res,rej]=await do_second('succeed');
          if(rej) {
             console.log('do_second() failed.');
             reject('failed');
          } else {
             console.log('do_second() succeeded.');
             resolve('success');
          }
       } else {
          console.log('do_first() succeeded, no call to do_second().');
          resolve('success');
       }
    });
  }

  do_first=async function(param) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       if(param==='fail') {
          console.log('rejecting do_first()');
          reject('failure');
       } else {
          console.log('resolving do_first()');
          resole('success');
       }
    });
  }

  do_second=async function(param) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       if(param==='fail') {
          console.log('rejecting do_second()');
          reject('failure');
       } else {
          console.log('resolving do_second()');
          resole('success');
       }
    });
  }
}

exports.MyClass = MyClass
```

If I try to run it with `node ./main.js` nothing happens. If I run `mc.do_stuff()` without the `await`, I do get the hello... Which boats am I missing?
For that matter: I am running NodeJS v18.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need to be changed here to make it work:

- When using `await`, only the `Promise.resolve` comes back to regular code execution. `Promise.reject` always raises an Exception.
- Typo `resole`
- changed code to consistently use arrow syntax. This requires referencing functions as instance members -> `this.do_first`. I suppose this was your intention. The syntax before did not execute the function as part of the object, but in global scope.

Here's your code in a working state

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.message = "hello";
  }

  do_stuff = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await this.do_first("fail");
        console.log("do_first() succeeded, no call to do_second().");
        resolve("success");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("do_first() failed.");

        try {
          await this.do_second("succeed");
          console.log("do_second() succeeded.");
          resolve("success");
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("do_second() failed.");
          reject("failed");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  do_first = async (param) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (param === "fail") {
        console.log("rejecting do_first()");
        reject("failure");
      } else {
        console.log("resolving do_first()");
        resolve("success");
      }
    });
  };

  do_second = async (param) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (param === "fail") {
        console.log("rejecting do_second()");
        reject("failure");
      } else {
        console.log("resolving do_second()");
        resolve("success");
      }
    });
  };
}

exports.MyClass = MyClass;
```

```
PS C:\Users\patrick\Documents\GitHub\stackoverflow-74714360> node ./main.js
rejecting do_first()
do_first() failed.
resolving do_second()
do_second() succeeded.
hello
```

Comment: Quite a few boats I missed there apparently... trying to learn. Did setup this little project to show the problem... typos were made (that's what you get when using vi to just quickly make something). 
You got the intention right, and I am trying to grab it all...

In the examples I have seen, I often saw construnctions like ```let [res,rej] = await something()``` and then testing on res and rej ... (e.g. in the https.request(...) function) so I copied that. It's something else I guess.
Thanks for the answer! It taught me much.

Comment: Might just be that I didn't come across this syntax yet. The ones I know well is either to attach to the promise, like promise.then(...).catch(...) or to try/catch with await. Glad to help.